# caption close to the table in caption of figure

Tags: tables, floats

I need guidance for making the picture below. I can't see to put the caption to the right of the small table `(a,b,c)`, as in the picture below. Any ideas?

[image]

This is my code:

```
\begin{figure*}
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=1.00\textwidth]{Fig01.png}       
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
       \hline
       \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{a}  \\\hline
       b & c \\\hline           
    \end{tabular}       
 \caption{Caption1 here...}
 \label{Fig:Fig01}  
 \end{center}
```

\end{figure*}

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). When asking questions it is better to provide a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) both in order to demonstrate what you are trying to do and to help others help you. The MWE should look like `\documentclass...\begin{document}...\end{document}`, it should compile and contain close to the minimal amount of code needed to explain/demonstrate what you are asking. This saves a lot of time for everyon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a starting point:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % demo is just for the example
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\kant[1-3]

\begin{figure*}
\centering

\includegraphics[width=1.00\textwidth]{Fig01.png}

\let\normalfigurename\figurename
\renewcommand{\figurename}{%
  \begin{tabular}[b]{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{a}  \\\hline
  b & c \\\hline
 \end{tabular}\ \normalfigurename}
\caption{Caption1 here...}
\label{Fig:Fig01}

\end{figure*}

\kant[4-8]

\end{document}
```

[image]